# Call prototype(javascript) function on link click?

Tags: php, javascript, prototypejs

I am working with AJAX with prototype and PHP. It is working for me but I need some small changes. Following is my running code for AJAX request:

**JS/Prototype:**

```
function ajaxRequest(url) {

    new Ajax.Request( url, {

          method: 'get',
          onSuccess: function( transport ) {

            // get json response
            var json = transport.responseText.evalJSON( true );
            alert(json);
        },     
        onFailure: function() {             
            alert('Error with AJAX request.'); 
        }  
    });

    return false;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href='javascript:ajaxRequest("/testajax/ajaxresponse");'>Testing AJAX</a>
```

**Question:**

Now I want to change my link like this:

```
<a href='/testajax/ajaxresponse' class='AjaxLink'>Testing AJAX</a>
```

So prototype function should capture click event of `class='AjaxLink'` links and then get href part of clicked link and proceed. How can I change my above prototype function for such kind of links.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wont work. Why do you want such a link? If a link is specified in this way any click on it will follow its href and change location of actual document. Only way to prevent such a behavior then is by adding onclick again or in *$(document).ready* bind onclick handler, and manualy cancel the event.

**UPDATE**
However to bind onclick event on all links with *AjaxLink* class,execute request and cancel the event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.AjaxLink').click(
      function(e){
        ajaxRequest(this.href);
        event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
      }
   ); 
});
```

Comment: I worked previously with jQuery with same type of links on some projects. In my current project I have to use prototype first time. So if we can achieve this by `$(document).ready()` , it is OK. Usually we use `prevetDefault()` function in jQuery to stop a link from `href` redirection. Can we not do this in prototype? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you have Prototype 1.7 then [this way](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Event/on/) is available:

```
document.on('click', 'a.AjaxLink', ajaxRequest.curry('/testajax/ajaxresponse'));
```

Otherwise you'll have to rely on good old [`Event.observe`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Event/observe/):

```
$$('a.AjaxLink').invoke('observe', 'click', 
    ajaxRequest.curry('/testajax/ajaxresponse'));
```

---

Just re-read the question and I see you want to use the href attribute. Jan Pfiefer was very close.

```
document.on('click', 'a.AjaxLink', function(event, element) {
    return ajaxRequest(element.href);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
$$('a.AjaxLink').each(function(element) {
    element.observe('click', function(e) {
        var element = e.element()
        Event.stop(e)          
        alert(element.href)
    });
})
```

Comment: Been years since I had to mess with Prototype. jQuery's syntax is so much sweeter.